# Non-null auto-incrementing column — but 'is null' query returns just-inserted row

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.1.60

And i have a table called "folder"

```
CREATE TABLE `folder` (
`folder_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
`parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`update_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`folder_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And i insert a value to it.

```
INSERT INTO `folder` (`name`) VALUES ('test_name');
```

just after that i execute a select query

query is

```
SELECT * FROM folder f WHERE f.folder_id IS NULL
```

But the surprising thing is that it actually return the last inserted row (only at the first run).

why this behavior happening in MySQL.

Comment: Yip I get the same result even on a different version of MySQL. Very strange indeed....

Comment: [No repro here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/2bde9/3)

Comment: I do not think so. folder_id is defined as not null and auto_increment. No row should be returned using the above query. Please refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a44f/1

Comment: hi @hims056 . i actually tested it in SQLYog in my local system.

Comment: My Software version: 5.5.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) I didn't get the same result. May be when you are inserting as mysql and other database software's uses file system it may be taking some time. You didn't mentioned you are using any server or running it in localhost ?

Comment: LIke I said I can reproduce the same behavior on my box checking version now and it is 5.1.69 on a centos distro.... very very weird and could lead to some serious problems.

Comment: @ARIF MAHMUD RANA. can you just follow this step 
1. create table
2. insert value
3. execute select query (only the first time i got the result)

Comment: Check your "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit" system variable

Comment: @user2130460 yes I did as you say I run it on phpmyadmin and I didn't get the result as you said

Comment: hi @ARIF MAHMUD RANA thanks 4 ur time . i tested in phpmyadmin and its working fine in phpmyadmin. But using SQLYog or via command line i still can reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually it is a bug in mysql 5.1.60 which you are using, and it is not a problem in early version of mysql.

however you can fix it in your current version of mysql by running this command:
mysql> SET sql_auto_is_null=0;

Answer (score 1):

Check your ["innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit)  system variable 
and set it to 1 and then try again

Comment: Yip seems like if you are fast enough the data is not flushed to disk thus allowing this behavior to propagate.

Comment: @Biju Soman thanks for your time . I checked the system variables in MySQL using **SHOW VARIABLES** query But the default value is 1 for **innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit**. Still i can reproduce the issue here.